# Use FileOpenPicker for windows phone 8

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, windows-phone-8.1

I believe, FileOpenPicker was added in Windows Phone SDK 8.1 which supports browsing through the music library, video library etc to let the user select a file. This functionality(API) was not available on windows phone 8 sdk. Problem is that windows phone sdk 8.1 can only be installed over visual studio 2013. I have installed VS2013 and SDK 8.1, When I build an app and try to deploy it on my windows phone running at 8.0 and not 8.1, it throws me an error saying it cannot be installed on this version of windows phone OS. 
I wonder, whatsapp did not had any option to browse videos up till sdk 8.0 was released. with the release of sdk 8.1, it lets user to browse videos from the video library. I hope they are also making use of the API mentioned above. But this updated version of whatsapp which supports video library browsing, works on my Windows Phone with OS 8.0? 
How were they able to use the API from 8.1 SDK and target the app for windows phone 8.0?
Is there any way I can created an app using SDK 8.1 and target the app to run on windows phone 8.0?

Answer (score 1):

WhatsApp is one of the most popular apps on the Windows Phone platform. As a result, they are occasionally granted access to APIs and capabilities that are not yet available in the public SDK.